# Why does assigning lambdas not work as expected in Python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

I know Python is supposed to have first class functions, and I've written some Python which "confirms" that, but the following explodes (runs out of stack depth) my IDLE in 3.5:

```
k = lambda x:x+1
k = lambda x:k (x+1)
k(0)
```

Shouldn't it evaluate to 2?

```
k = lambda x:x+1
j = lambda x:k (x+1)
j(0)
```

certainly does.

Comment: are you saying it's triggering infinite recursion in IDLE (which I could believe) or that it should right evaluate to an infinite loop (which is not what I expect)? If the latter, I would expect the RHS k in the 2nd line to evaluate back to the lambda in the first line, updating `k` to `lambda x: (x+1)+1`. (I'm happy to be told that the rest of CS doesn't expect this if that's the case.)

Comment: lambdas are "late binding". The value of k is not checked until the lambda is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Visualize with `lambda`

A little printing may help to understand what is going on:

```
k = lambda x: x+1
print('before:', id(k))
k = lambda x: print('in    :', id(k))
k(0)
print('after :', id(k))

before: 4428659024
in    : 4428658208
after : 4428658208
```

The `id` of the last `lambda` is the same as the one use inside it. This nicely demonstrates the late binding.

### Translate into function statements

Things might a bit clearer if you translate the `lambda`s into function define with `def`:

```
def k(x):
    return x + 1

def k(x):
    return k(x+1)
k(0)
```

It is pretty clear that the first definition does make sense as it is overridden by the second one.

In addition, even you use different names for the functions and re-assign the function name:

```
def k(x):
    return x + 1

def j(x):
    return k(x+1)

k = j
```

it appears to be clearer that the first function definition doesn't make sense because the function can never be reached.

Comment: Also, PEP8 specifies that you shouldn't bind lambda's at all: "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier." So as a style guideline, the OP should avoid what they are trying.

Comment: @Dalum Good point. You can always do it with a `def` and it is often better. The two extra lines can make things much easier to understand. I still remember the heated discussion to remove  `lambda` from Python 3 all together.

Answer (score 1):

The name lookup of `k` is done at runtime, which means that the function calls itself an infinite number of times (and that the first line does nothing useful). If you want the result you expect then you will have to use the ternary operator to return immediately instead of recursing.

Comment: Sorry, which ternary operator is that (I only know the "if expression"). (and googling seems to only turn that up)

Comment: Yes, that would be Python's ternary operator.